# IIS_IUSRS doesn't exist to be added on Synology share

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016, synology

I used to have my website running on a physical Windows Server 2016 machine with IIS 10 which accessed its data files on an old Netgear NAS.  I have since replaced the NAS with a Synology RS815+ running DSM 6.2.4-25556 Update 6 and virtualized the web server, with the intention of also running the website off of a NAS share.  Just as what automatically happens with inetpub\wwwroot, I need to enable read permissions on the website folder as well as the data files to be served for IIS_IUSRS.  The Synology is joined to my domain.

When I access any specific NAS folder's Properties/Security, click Edit and Add, enter "IIS" and click Check Names, I get the Name Not Found box.  I've checked everything I can think of.  Is there a DSM setting I'm missing?  Or is this truly a Windows issue?  Currently, the website is up on C:, but that's not ideal on my VM, and it can't access its data files to be useful.  Can anybody help get my site up again?

Comment: Does the user or group in question exist in AD?

Comment: `<Machine name>/IIS_IUSRS` is a local group, so it is impossible to configure it across machine boundary. Configure the application pool to use a domain service account, and then on NAS side you can grant that account the right permissions. Note that mapping IIS sites to a file share in general not a good idea. Files should be hosted on the IIS machine for best performance.